Is this tutorial correct about ergonomics?
I'm doubting this image from my Uni's tutorial:

Is there a reasonable basis for not resting your wrists in a "kdb cushion" when typing ?

Does this answer your question? Injury because of bad ergonomics

There is.. sort of. It's a question that doesn't have a one-size-fits-all answer (like a lot of ergonomics specifics), The position shown in your post is a decent "default" for most people - and it's going to be better than people mis-using wrist-rests and unwittingly causing damage but the real answer is that you should follow the advice of a medical or occupational health professional as to what is the right solution for you and your body.
Basically using a wrist rest alleviates tension in the neck and shoulders at the cost of increased pressure on the undersides of the wrists (although still less than using the edge of the desk itself of course) which in turn might cause carpal tunnel and/or tenosynovitis to develop (Top Tip: you don't want either of those, I speak from experience and they aren't fun), keeping your wrists clear like in the photo means there's no pressure on those vulnerable areas at all but your neck and shoulders are going to be working harder to keep your forearms up.
So if you're using a wrist rest then it should be soft, rounded and at a suitable height so that your wrists are in a suitably neutral position and the pressure on the tendons is minimised. Ideally the contact point of a rest should be more on the underside of your palms rather than the wrist, this allows you to get the benefits of reduced tension on the neck/shoulder area without doing damage to the wrists - this is how my own set-up is for example because issues with my neck and shoulders mean it's key for me to reduce tension in that area.
